Is there a Messenger sharer link similar to Facebook's for sharing URLs on mobile and desktop?
I've been using the Facebook sharer link to share URLs easily. The link looks something like this:
http://www.facebook.com/dialog/send?u=PAGE_URL
I find it very convenient for sharing content directly through Facebook's dialog. Now, I'm looking for a similar functionality specifically for Facebook Messenger.
Does anyone know if there is a sharer link for Messenger that works on both mobile and desktop platforms? I want to be able to share a URL in Messenger just as seamlessly as with the Facebook sharer link.
Thank you!
I found some examples, but none of the works, for example:
fb-messenger://share/?link= PAGE_URL
